# Keep the same value of textarea and textbox in ms word when convert from html

Tags: php

Suppose I have a form like this:

**html2doc.php**

```
 <form method="post" action="htmltodoc.php">
  <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea cols="3" rows="2" name="textArea" value=<?=($_POST['textArea'])?>></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Candidate Name:</td>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="txtCandidate" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {                   
                header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=html2doc.doc");
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

**What I need:**

When the user input data into textarea and text box it will keep all the data when I convert it to Ms word.

**The problems:**

When I covert it to word document,it will not display the data that user input in the form of html.

Any ideas on how to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<textarea>` doesn't have an attribute called `value`.

Comment: Augh... Don't use `<?=($_POST['textArea'])?>` use `<?php echo $_POST['textArea']; ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

`<textarea>` doesn't have an attribute called `value`. For contents of `<textarea>` you should not use `value`. You need to give them inside the tags. Change it this way:

```
<textarea cols="3" rows="2" name="textArea"><?php echo $_POST['textArea']; ?></textarea>
```

And also, it is not a good idea to use short codes starting with `<?`.